# How to add shadow or glow around a Jasper Reports frame element?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to add a shadow around a Jasper Reports frame element via jrxml code. Currently, I have an outline style applied to a frame:

```
<style name="Frame-style">
    <box>
        <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>

<frame>
    <reportElement positionType="Float" style="Frame-style" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="512" height="100"/>
</frame>
```

The code above produces a frame with a 1.0 px black border. Unfortunately, I do not see how I can add a shadow or glow. Is this possible? Can I use HTML with CSS to achieve this?

I will use the compiled .jasper file to generate a PDF document.